# How to set the featured image of a post from the Media Library

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

If I create a post with this function:

```
function write_post_with_featured_image( $post_title, $categories ) {
    $category_names_array = explode( ",", $categories );

    $category_ids = array( );
    foreach ( $category_names_array as $category_name ) {
        $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category_name );
        array_push( $category_ids, $category_id );
    }

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array( 
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $post_title ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => $category_ids,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    echo "post_id: " . $post_id;
}
```

How can I set it's featured image already existing in the Media Library?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully everyone will enjoy this function that creates a post and set's it's featured image from the Media Library:

```
function write_post_with_featured_image($post_title, $categories, $image_in_library_url) {
        $category_names_array = explode(",", $categories);

        $category_ids = array();
        foreach ($category_names_array as $category_name) {
            $category_id = get_cat_ID($category_name);
            array_push($category_ids, $category_id);
        }

        // Create post object
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title),
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => $category_ids
        );


        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id=wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        echo "post_id:" . $post_id;

        //Get Image Attachment Id
        $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $image_in_library_url );
        echo "attachment_id:" . $attachment_id;

        // And finally assign featured image to post
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
        echo "featured image added";
    }
}

$post_title = 'My Super Post';
$categories = 'Category1,Category2';
$image_in_library_url = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/my-super-image.jpg";
write_post_with_featured_image($post_title,$categories,$image_in_library_url);
```